# DI, concrete class with abstract, generic parent

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, .net-core

We are using .NET Core's Dependency Injection and have the following class structure

```
public interface IValidator<TEntity, TMessageKey> {
   ValidationResult<TMessageKey> Validate(TEntity entityToValidate);
}

public abstract class BaseValidator<TEntity, TMessageKey> : IValidator<TEntity, TMessageKey> {
  // code omitted
}

public class ConcreteValidator : BaseValidator<ConcerteEntity, MyMessageKey> 
{
  // code omitted
}
```

of course there may be many concrete validators and I want to batch register them.

How would I achieve that?

Basically I want to register multiple closed generic types to one open generic type.

Every thing I tried failed so far.

- Registering `BaseValidator<,>` to `ConcreteValidator
- Registering `IValidator<,>` to `BaseValidator<,>`

I already read multiple articles/posts about it and I'm not even sure if it is even possible with .net core's DI

EDIT:
Here's my last try (I'm using NetCore.AutoRegisterDi extension)

```
var data = services.RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Where(x => x.BaseType.IsGenericType && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseValidator<,>));

foreach(var d in data.TypesToConsider)
{
   var type = typeof(BaseValidator<,>);
   var genericType = type.MakeGenericType(d.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments);
   services.AddScoped(genericType, d);
}
```

Comment: Ok, after some more researching, I came to the conclusion that I was way overthinking it.

Since we inject the concrete class, all we have to do ist
`services.AddScoped(typeof(ConcreteValidator), typeof(ConcreteValidator)`

Comment: If your classes depend on a `ConcreteValidator` instead of an abstraction, you don't need the `IValidator<T>` abstraction at all. On the other hand, it will cause strong coupling between the consumer and the validator, which might make it more difficult to (unit) test and maintain your application.